# equivalence of arg max for continuous functions

Tags: optimization, continuity

Let $$a(x)=\alpha f(x)+\beta+g(x) $$ and $$b(x)=\gamma f(x)+\delta +g(x)$$where $f,g$ are continuous real-valued functions on a closed interval $[0,c]$ and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are constants with $\alpha,\beta\geq0$.

Is it possible to prove that: $$\arg\max_{x\in[0,c]}a(x) = \arg\max_{x\in[0,c]}b(x) $$And if so, under which conditions (for instance $\gamma>0$) ?

Comment: For one thing, you don't have to worry about the $\beta$ and $\delta$, since they are just additive constants so don't affect the locations of maxima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for a moment that your functions are differentiable, then necessary condition for optimality would give

$$0=\alpha f'(x)+g'(x),$$

$$0=\gamma f'(x)+g'(x).$$

In the general case, there would be no reason why the solution to these equations would be the same.

Otherwise, you can simply pick for example $g(x) = -x^2$ and $f(x) = M \geq 0$.